# iOS Push Notifications to specific user in the same deviceToken

Tags: objective-c, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using Urban Airship to test push notification and it went well.

My problem is how do I specify which user to get the notification not just the device token.

I mean in some situations where one device has multiple users, so many users registered the same device token to server.

Or do I have to do the filter on the device (client side) itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no real way to do what you want unfortunately. In APNS there's only such thing as a device. You push a device and it shows a message / badge / sound on that device.

If your app can have multiple users associated with it then you'd need to work out from the push which user it relates to and handle it accordingly. How you do that would depend on your app but you could add in a custom key to the push which indicated the user it's for.

If your app only ever has one user logged in at once then I suggest that when you hand the push token to your server, the server first turns off push for the user that the token was originally registered for and subsequently turns push on for the new user.

Comment: The idea of handling push notification on server is great! Thanks.

Comment: @mattjgalloway do you have any knowledge in this matter about other services, such as GCM and MPNS?